# Attach information to Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: java, compiler-construction, annotation-processing

I would like to attach some information to javax.lang.model.element.Element objects or com.sun.source.tree.Tree objects so that I can access that information later.

```
    class Visitor extends ElementKindVisitor8<Void, Void> {

      @Override
      public Boolean visitType(TypeElement e, Void v) {

        if(!e.hasAttribute()) {
          boolean v = expensiveCheck(e);
          e.setAttribute(v);
        } 

        return e.getAttribute();
      }
    }
```

I am wondering about the best way to achieve this? One solution that came to my mind was to use a map such as

```
    Map<String, Boolean> attributes = ...;
    attributes.put(e.getQualifiedName(), expensiveCheck(e));
```

However, that does not work for Methods or Fields because they don't have an unambiguous name.

A solution dependent on com.sun.source.tree would also be totally fine.

Comment: `java.util.HashMap<TypeElement, Boolean> attributes...` will solve the "unambiguous" name problem for you. If two objects happen to have same `hash code`, they will drop into the same hash bucket but when fetched later you'll get the correct value back. See http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l566 for details